# js code snippet running differently than on local server

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is part of the code for a morse code translator I tried to make, with part of the JS code written by [Louys Patrice Bessette](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2159528/louys-patrice-bessette). In the JS code snippet provided by this user in an answer to another question runs perfectly, but after implementing the code in a JS file for part of the webpage, the user needs to type another character or space after a word in one textarea to complete it in morse code in a second textarea.

```js
let eng = {
    "a": " ._",
    'b': ' _...',
    'c': ' _._.',
    'd': ' _..',
    'e':' .',
    'f': ' .._.',
    'g': ' __.',
};

let input = document.getElementById('input');
let output = document.getElementById('output');
input.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
    out = eng2mc(input.value);
    output.value = out;
})

function eng2mc(string) {
  let output = "";
  const characters = string.toLowerCase().split("")
  console.log(characters)
  for (let character of characters) {
    console.log(character)
    if (character === " ") {
      output += "    "  // 4 spaces (+3 of last letter, makes 7)
    } else if(eng[character]){
      output += eng[character] + "   "  // 3 spaces between letters
    }
  }
  return output
}
```

```css
.boxparent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 50%;
}

.textbox {
    font-size: .8rem;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-family: Palatino Linotype;
    padding:10px;
    line-height:1.5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow:1.25px 1.25px 1.25px #222222;
    resize: none;
}

#entertext {
    position:absolute;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-left:585px;
    font-family: Palatino Linotype;
}

#input {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}

#output {
    position:relative;
    right:-16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<head>
    <title>Morse Code Translator</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<style>
body {
    background-color:#555555;
}
</style>
<body>
<br>
<form class="boxparent" method="post">
    <textarea class="textbox" id="input" rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="Enter text here"> </textarea>
    <textarea readonly class="textbox" id="output" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
</form>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be vastly simplified. Also use `input` event to allow pasting instead of the keypress that gives you the problem

```js
const eng = { " ": "    ", "a": " ._", "b": " _...", "c": " _._.", "d": " _..", "e": " .", "f": " .._.", "g": " __." };
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const output = document.getElementById('output');
const eng2mc = string => string
  .trim()
  .toLowerCase()
  .split("")
  .map(char => eng[char] || "?")
  .join("   ");
input.addEventListener('input', () =>   output.value = eng2mc(input.value));
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #555555;
}

.boxparent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 50%;
}

.textbox {
  font-size: .8rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: Palatino Linotype;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1.25px 1.25px 1.25px #222222;
  resize: none;
}

#entertext {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 585px;
  font-family: Palatino Linotype;
}

#input {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

#output {
  position: relative;
  right: -16px;
}
```

```html
<form class="boxparent" method="post">
  <textarea class="textbox" id="input" rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="Enter text here"> </textarea>
  <textarea readonly class="textbox" id="output" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is simply due to the `keypress` event. It fires before the actual pressed key is registered. Using `keyup` is better in that case.

```js
let eng = {
    "a": " ._",
    'b': ' _...',
    'c': ' _._.',
    'd': ' _..',
    'e':' .',
    'f': ' .._.',
    'g': ' __.',
};

let input = document.getElementById('input');
let output = document.getElementById('output');
input.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {  // keyup!!!
    out = eng2mc(input.value);
    output.value = out;
})

function eng2mc(string) {
  let output = "";
  const characters = string.toLowerCase().split("")
  console.log(characters)
  for (let character of characters) {
    console.log(character)
    if (character === " ") {
      output += "    "  // 4 spaces (+3 of last letter, makes 7)
    } else if(eng[character]){
      output += eng[character] + "   "  // 3 spaces between letters
    }
  }
  return output
}
```

```css
.boxparent {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 50%;
}

.textbox {
    font-size: .8rem;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-family: Palatino Linotype;
    padding:10px;
    line-height:1.5;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow:1.25px 1.25px 1.25px #222222;
    resize: none;
}

#entertext {
    position:absolute;
    font-size:20px;
    margin-left:585px;
    font-family: Palatino Linotype;
}

#input {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
}

#output {
    position:relative;
    right:-16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<head>
    <title>Morse Code Translator</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<style>
body {
    background-color:#555555;
}
</style>
<body>
<br>
<form class="boxparent" method="post">
    <textarea class="textbox" id="input" rows="10" cols="80" placeholder="Enter text here"> </textarea>
    <textarea readonly class="textbox" id="output" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
</form>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```